# Get the coordinates from a HashMap

Tags: java, android, hashmap, coordinates

This is what I want to do:The user will introduce a string, if that string exists in my HashMap then the gotoLocation method will be called and the map will center on the corresponding marker for that string. The problem is that I cannot manage to get the Latlng from the HashMap. This is what I have so far:

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    GoogleMap mMap;
    HashMap<String, LatLng> thePlaces;
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    Marker myPosition;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();


        assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);


        thePlaces = new HashMap<String, LatLng>();
        thePlaces.put("Thirsty Monk", new LatLng(43.607044, 1.450307));
        thePlaces.put("Cocolino", new LatLng(43.571505, 1.417759));
        thePlaces.put("The Melting Pot", new LatLng(43.607469, 1.447162));
        thePlaces.put("De Danu", new LatLng(43.600723, 1.455917));
        thePlaces.put("Carciuma", new LatLng(43.604892, 1.476562));
        thePlaces.put("Boca", new LatLng(43.604496, 1.474924));
        thePlaces.put("Bar Acasa", new LatLng(43.604781, 1.474502));


         //AutoCompleteTextView t1 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        setThePlaces(thePlaces.keySet().toArray(new String[1000]));
    }

    private void setThePlaces (String searchString[]){
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, searchString);
        AutoCompleteTextView t1 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        assert t1 != null;
        t1.setThreshold(2);
        t1.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    protected void onStart() {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.location:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.map_type:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Map Type selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.share_app:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Share the APP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;


        LatLng cityView = new LatLng(43.604346, 1.443760);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(cityView, 12));


        MarkerOptions beerMarker = new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.beer_marker));


        // The Thirsty Monk
        LatLng thirstyMonk = new LatLng(43.607044, 1.450307);
        mMap.addMarker(beerMarker.position(thirstyMonk).title("The Thirsty Monk").snippet("Text example!" + "\n text example second line"));
        // The Cocolino
        LatLng cocolino = new LatLng(43.571505, 1.417759);
        mMap.addMarker(beerMarker.position(cocolino).title("Cocolino").snippet("Lets do the twist"));
        //The Melting Pot
        LatLng meltingPot = new LatLng(43.607469, 1.447162);
        mMap.addMarker(beerMarker.position(meltingPot).title("The Melting Pot"));
        //De Danu
        LatLng deDanu = new LatLng(43.600723, 1.455917);
        mMap.addMarker(beerMarker.position(deDanu).title("De Danu"));
        //Carciuma
        LatLng carciuma = new LatLng(43.604892, 1.476562);
        mMap.addMarker(beerMarker.position(carciuma).title("Carciuma"));
        //Boca
        LatLng boca = new LatLng(43.604496, 1.474924);
        mMap.addMarker(beerMarker.position(boca).title("Boca"));
        //Bar Acasa
        LatLng barAcasa = new LatLng(43.604781, 1.474502);
        mMap.addMarker(beerMarker.position(barAcasa).title("Bar Acasa"));

    }

    public void gotoLocation(double lat, double lng, float zoom) {

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom);
        mMap.moveCamera(update);
    }

    private void hideSoftKeyboard(View v) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }


    public void locateFromString(View view) {

        hideSoftKeyboard(view);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String searchString = tv.getText().toString();


        if (thePlaces.containsKey(searchString)){

            Toast.makeText(this,"The place exists in the list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"The place DOESN'T EXIST in the list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You've posted a *lot* of code, most of which is irrelevant to the question... but you haven't included vital information such as what you're actually observing. What's the value of `searchString` when you debug into the code, for example?

Comment: `LatLng loc = thePlaces.get(searchString)`, no? And condider refactor of `gotoLocation()` method to make it accept `LatLng` instead of separate `lat` and `lon` so you won't need to create a new `latLng`.

Comment: Thanks Sasha, it worked:) I have added your code to the locateFromString method and I deleted entirely the gotoLocation method as I do not see it relevant right now, as I can create the latLng in the if statement. Is there any problem from Your point of view? How can I mark your answer as the correct one?

Comment: @Jon sorry for that I posted everything as I didn't want to miss something. I don't understand exactly your question. searchString should provide me the LatLng coordinates...Doing what Sasha suggested worked.

Comment: My question is what you've observed - you said it didn't work, but not what happened... whether you saw "The place exists in the list" or not. If you're just missing `Map.get()`, I'd strongly urge you to read a collections tutorial and/or the docs to get the hang of the other operations available.

Comment: Yes I got "the place exists in the list", and yes I know that I have a lot to read, but I was looking for a quick fix:-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String placeKey "APlaceKey";

LatLng selectedValue = null;
if (thePlaces.get(placeKey) != null) {
    selectedValue = thePlaces.get(placeKey);
}

if (selectedValue != null) {
// do your code here with the selected LatLng
}
```